# ASP.Net ListView and event handling

Tags: c#, events, listview, delegates, nested

I have an `.ascx` which contains a listview.  Let's call it the parent.
Within its `ItemTemplate` I reference a second .ascx which is basically another `ListView`, let's call it the child.  On the parent, the child control is wrapped in a placeholder tag.  I use this place holder tag to show and hide the child.

**Psuedo code:**

```
<asp:Placeholder id="plhChild" runat="server" visible="false" >
    <uc0:childList id="childListCtl" runat="server" />
</asp:Placeholder>
```

The child listview has a 'close' button in its Layout Template.  Let's call it `btnClose` with an `OnClick` event of `btnClose_Click`.  I want to use this button to set the visibility of the containing placeholder.

I'm trying to avoid doing something like using
`PlaceHolder plhChild = (PlaceHolder)childListCtl.NamingContainer` since I can't guarantee every instance of the child .ascx will be contained within a placeholder.

I tried creating an event in the child that could be subscribed to.

**Psuedo code:**

```
public delegate CloseButtonHandler();
public event CloseButtonHandler CloseButtonEvent;
```

And in the actual `btnClose_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)` event I have:

```
if (CloseButtonEvent != null) CloseButtonEvent();
```

My problem is that the delegate `CloseButtonEvent` is always `null`.

I've tried assigning the delegate in the listview's `OnDatabound` event of the parent and on the click event, to set the `plhChild.visible = true`, and I've stepped through the code and know the  delegate instantiation works in both place, but again, when it gets to the `btnClose_Click` event on the child, the delegate is null.

Answer (score 0):

Add your event declaratively:

**Parent Control:**

```
<EditItemTemplate> 
     <uc1:WebUserControlTest ID="WebUserControlTest1" runat="server" 
        OnCloseButtonEvent="CloseButtonEventCatcher" />              
</EditItemTemplate>    

protected void CloseButtonEventCatcher()
{
    string here = "here is the event";
}
```

**Child Control Code-behind:**

```
public delegate void CloseButtonHandler();
public event CloseButtonHandler CloseButtonEvent;

protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseButtonEvent();
}
```